# What changes can `git stash` apply to, changes in working directory or/and changes in stage?

Tags: git

I `git add` some changes on a feature branch, and then realized that I should have worked on a new feature branch.

Thanks to [jmargolisvt's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48156644/156458),  I found a solution: I then ran `git stash` without undoing `git add` ( i.e. I didn't run `git reset HEAD .`),  and then `git checkout master`, `git pull`, `git checkout -b newbranch`, and `git stash pop`. 
Now the changes are on my new branch, and not on my original branch.

jmargolisvt pointed out that `git stash` can only stash changes in working directory, instead of changes in stage (i.e. changes that `git add` has been applied to), so I should have run `git reset HEAD .` to undo `git add` before running `git stash`. But my case shows that `git stash` can stash changes to which `git add` has been applied. So I wonder what is the truth?

Thanks.

Comment: Using interactive rebasing and cherry-picking there is almost unlimited flexibility what you can do with changes. In this case, you could as well have committed the changes in the current branch, checked out a new branch and cherry-picked the commit there. I tend not to use `git stash` that much, proper commits are IMHO a more powerful tool which better integrates with most GUIs.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thanks for the advice. Could you give specific git commands? If I understand correctly, first run `git commit` on my current feature branch,  then run `git checkout master` to switch to master and check out a new branch by `git checkout -b newfeaturebranch`, and finally how to do cherry-pick the commit I created last on my original feature branch?

Comment: You need `git cherry-pick ...` with `...` being either a single commit or a range. The single commit can be either a SHA-hash identifying a commit, but also things like `branch-name~2` while a range is two such commits joined by a literal `..`. Make sure you read the docs for `git cherry-pick`, `git rebase`, `git merge`, `git reset` and `git reflog`. In particular, you can always back off using `git (merge|cherry-pick|rebase) --abort` or using `git reset` and you can use `git reflog` to retrace your steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git stash` command violates some of the normal generally-applicable rules about Git, but in ways that eventually turn out to be mostly unsurprising.  Let's take a little side trip to review things you probably already know, but may not have actually recognized as significant.  After that, let's look at what `git stash` does.

#### Git is mainly about commits

The first thing you need to know about Git is that it's mostly about *commits*, which are identified by *hash IDs*.  These hash IDs, which you will see in `git log` output, are useless to mere humans because there's no way to keep them straight.  So Git augments them with names like `master`—which is a *branch name*—or `v1.2`, a tag name; or `origin/feature`, which is a *remote-tracking name*.<sup>1</sup>  Each such name stores one (and only 1) hash ID.  We say that these names *point to* a commit:

```
a123456   <-- master
```

Each commit also stores a hash ID, which is the commit's *parent*.  This makes the child commit "point back to" its parent.  This lets Git follow a chain: start from the most recent commit—the one to which `master` points, for instance—and do something with it; then do the same thing with that commit's parent; then do it again with the parent's parent (the grandparent), and so on.  That's what `git log` does, for instance.  So really, we have:

```
... <-3c39aef <-a123456   <-- master
```

The name `master` leads to commit `a123456`, and then commit `a123456` leads back to some earlier commit, and so on.  Git, in other words, works *backwards*.

---

<sup>1</sup>These are also called *remote-tracking branch names*.  I don't like the phrase *remote-tracking branch* as the word "branch" is already pretty heavily loaded.  (The word "track" is overloaded too!  At least the word *remote* is usually used pretty consistently.)  These names just remember the hash ID stored under a branch name in some *other* repository.

---

#### The index

The process of making a *new* commit, in Git, is straightforward, but at first surprising to anyone who has used almost any other version control system.  When you run `git commit`, Git takes whatever is currently in your *index* and uses that to make a new commit.  Since this new commit is new, it gets a new, unique hash ID, different from every existing commit's hash ID.  The new commit holds a snapshot of whatever was in the index.  You are, of course, the author of the new commit; and the new commit's *parent* commit is the commit you had checked out just a moment ago, before you made the new one.

In other words, if, just a moment ago, `a123456` *was* the current commit, and you ran `git commit`, now `a123456` is the *parent* of the new current commit, with its new hash ID.  Let's assume that the new hash ID is `b789abc`:

```
... <-a123456 <-b789abc   <-- master
```

That Git uses this thing called the *index* is the first surprising part.  Most version control systems have something like it, but keep it hidden; but Git *requires* that you know about the index.  Meanwhile, the fact that the ID to which `master` points changes is the second surprising part.

#### Branch names

Note that the branch *name* `master` doesn't really know anything about the branch itself.  All it does is store the one hash ID!  Well, there's one more feature: it *automatically changes as you make new commits*.  That's what's special about branch names.  They *automatically change when you commit*.

To choose which branch name should change, you run `git checkout branch`.  This also chooses which commit you have checked out.  The commit you have checked out right now is the same one the name identifies.  This is true at all times, by definition: if you have a *branch* checked out, the branch *name* "points to" (has as its value) the commit hash ID, and that's the *commit* you have checked out.

#### The work-tree, and tracked, untracked, and ignored files

All files stored inside Git—in the repository, or even just in the index—are in special, often highly-compressed forms.  The Git commands are often the only things on your computer that can deal with these compressed files.  So Git needs a way to have copies of these files that are in their ordinary form, so that you can work with (or on) them.  That's the *work-tree*.

Git also has this general idea of untracked files.  The index gets right in your face here, even though you can't *see* it: Git defines a *tracked* file as one that's *in the index*.  Git defines an *untracked* file as one that's *not* in the index.  Specifically, it's a file that *is* in the work-tree, but *not* in the index.

Since `git commit` makes new commits out of whatever is in the index, we can see from this definition that whatever's *not* tracked does not go into a new commit.  (This is going to be highly relevant to `git stash`.)

When you first `git checkout` any existing commit, usually by using `git checkout` on a branch name, Git generally fills the index with whatever is in that commit.  So now the index matches the commit.  Git then extracts everything from the index into the work-tree.  So now the work-tree matches the index, which matches the current commit.  In other words, you have *three copies of every file*.

When you run `git add filename`, what you are really doing is telling Git: *copy `filename` from the work-tree into the index.*  If the file was already in the index, you are simply replacing the data, updating it to whatever you put in the work-tree.  If the file was not in the index before, well, now it is, and now it is *tracked*.  It's not committed yet—you've merely copied it into the index.  But now it's in the index, so it's tracked.

When Git comes across an untracked file—a file that's in the work-tree, but not in the index—Git tends to *complain* about it.  Git can be very whiny and noisy.  So `.gitignore` lets you tell Git: *Hey, you know this file that's untracked?  It's **supposed to be** untracked.  Shut up about that already!*  This also tells Git not to *start* tracking the file—i.e., not to add it to the index—if you use an en-masse `git add .` or `git add --all`.  It never takes the file *out* of the index if it's already there, though, so listing a file in `.gitignore` never *gets rid of* the file.  It only has an effect on *untracked* files.

In any case, once you have used `git add` to copy files into the index, you can make a new commit that saves that version of that file forever, under the hash ID that Git assigns to the new commit.  If you run `git commit` to make the new commit, the new commit gets added at the end of the current branch, because Git assigns the new commit into the branch name.

## Git stash

So, finally, we can look at what `git stash` does.  (Note: I'm going to ignore `git stash -u` and `git stash -a` here, and just cover "normal" stashes.)  What `git stash save` actually does is to make *two commits*.  There's something a little bit unusual about the process, but Git uses the same commit mechanisms as before.

The first of these two commits saves the index.  Since Git is built around making commits *from* the index, this is actually the easy part.  Let's say you're on a commit whose hash ID is just `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

The funny thing about `git stash`'s first commit is that it doesn't go on branch `master` at all.  In fact, it goes onto *no* branch.  Let's represent this index commit with the letter `i`, in lowercase:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
        |
        i
```

Then, `git stash` goes on to make a second commit.  This one is harder to make, and what it does is use a spare, extra, *temporary* index to make it.  Git fills the temporary index in by copying, into the new temporary index, everything from the normal index but updated according to whatever files are in the work-tree.  That is, the new temporary index starts out as a copy of the original index, then has work-tree files added to it (or removed from it if they're missing).  Now Git makes that second commit, but makes it with not one but *two* parents.  Let's call this second commit `w` for "work-tree":

```
...--G--H   <-- master
        |\
        i-w
```

The last step of `git stash` is to set up a name to remember the hash ID of this `w` commit.  Git uses the special name `refs/stash` (which is not a branch name):

```
...--G--H   <-- master
        |\
        i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

Note that untracked files appear in *neither commit:* neither `i` nor `w` have any untracked files.  If you did run `git add` on some files, though, those files *are* in both `i` and `w` (and the contents in the `i` and `w` commits match, unless you changed the work-tree copy again *after* `git add`ing it to the index).

Later, when you `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` the `i-w` pair, Git will extract whatever files are in those commits, compare them to what's in the `H` commit, and use that to build the changes in your index and/or work-tree.

#### Conclusion

So, this is what you should know about `git stash`:

- It makes commits.
- The commits it makes are really just like any other commits you could make, except that they're not on any branch.
- Because they're on *no* branch, they won't be copied by `git rebase` (which is mostly about copying old commits to newer, presumably improved, commits).
- What's in those commits is whatever was in the index when you ran `git stash`, which is the same as the rule for any ordinary commits you make.
- You can always just make ordinary commits instead of using `git stash`.  Unless you're pretty sure you have a quick and easy case, that's often a better way to work anyway.

There are some more advanced things to know, such as the use of `-u` (aka `--include-untracked`) and `-a` (aka `--all`) and `-k` (aka `--keep-index`), but those are tricky to deal with correctly.  I have seen a lot of cases of people using these without understanding them, where they get into trouble later.  (In particular, extracting `-u` and `-a` stashes can be problematic.  The `-k` option, which I think is primarily meant for testing, is also a bit tricky to use in any automated way.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you also explain what happens when running `git stash pop`? How does it deal with the i-w pair of commits created by `git stash push`?

Comment: `git stash pop` = `git stash apply && git stash drop`: apply, then drop if Git thinks the `i-w` pair was applied successfully. So `apply` is the more interesting verb here. You choose, at this time, whether to use the `i` commit. If you choose not to use it, only the `w` commit really matters, and Git winds up just throwing the `i` commit away entirely. So: are you applying with `--index` ("keep and use `i`"), or without `--index` ("discard `i`")?

Comment: I ran `git stash save`, so it didn't create the i commit, correct? So when I ran `git stash pop`, it only recovered files from the w commit to the working tree, and had no the i commit to recover files from to the index?

Comment: `git stash save` *makes* the `i-w` stash pair. What *uses* it is `git stash apply` (or `git stash pop`, but I recommend to *avoid* that one and use separate `apply` and then `drop` once you're happy). *How* it uses the pair depends on whether you run `git stash apply --index`. So, here you used `git stash apply` without `--index`: that ignores the `i` commit and uses only the `w` commit.

Comment: Thanks. What are your favorite or recommended books or references for git?

Comment: The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is probably the best single reference. I am, however, in spare time (which I have little of), working on my own...

Comment: @Tim: mostly by digging into the Git source.

Answer (score 2):

`git stash` stashes anything that is not committed. So this includes changes that are staged but not yet committed (i.e., everything that is `git add`ed).

However: you shouldn't really be bothered with this as long as you're not pushing your changes. Simply commit, do a `git checkout -b newbranchname`, and if you want to reset your other branch back to the origin, do a `checkout` of your previous branch and reset it to it's tracking branch: `git checkout oldbranchname && git reset origin/oldbranchname`

If you get comfortable with juggling your local branches around, you'll be much more flexible. `git stash` is really only useful if you want a quick step back to what's the commit your on.

Remember: a branch is not really a branch. It's just a name pointing to a commit.

Comment: Thanks. "you want to reset your other branch back to the origin", does "your other branch" mean the old branch or the new branch? Did `git checkout -b newbranchname` make "your other branch" not tracking the origin?

Comment: The checkout does not change anything about which branches are tracking which. I believe that will answer both these questions :)

Comment: If `git checkout -b newbranchname` doesn't change which branch tracking which, why is it possible that one may want to reset "your other branch" back to the origin?

Comment: It depends if you committed first and then branched off, or if you branched off first and then committed. In the former case, you will want to reset the first branch to the origin in order to avoid accidentally pushing commits. In the latter case, you don't, that's right, but in that case you would assume there is only one commit in your new branch, not several. (that was my train of thought) :)

Answer (score 1):

`git stash` by default stashes everything tracked but not on HEAD (i.e. files with changes whether in the index or not). If you want to make a stash but leave your index untouched (i.e. keep the effects of `git add`), you can use `git stash save --keep-index`. If you want to add files to your stash that aren't yet tracked by git, you can use `git stash save --include-untracked`. More options here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Comment: Thanks. Does `git stash` by default undo `git add`? "If you want to make a stash but leave your index untouched (i.e. keep the effects of git add), you can use git stash save --keep-index"

Comment: @Tim yes it does. By default it tries to get your state back to HEAD.