# Why do I want to unstage with `git reset HEAD`" before stashing?

Tags: git

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48156644/156458 says

> So you've `git add`-ed your changes, so they are currently staged. 
>   First **you want to unstage them with `git reset HEAD .`** assuming you
>   are the top level in your directory.  The files should all be (most
>   likely) red now, indicating there are unstaged changes.
>
> Now you can `git stash` those changes while you create a new branch. 
>   `git checkout <<master branch name>>` then `git checkout -b <<new
>   topic branch name>>`.
>
> You've got a clean copy of master now, so let's get those stashed
>   changes with `git stash pop`.  Now you're back to where you started,
>   with all your already committed changes in the trunk and your new
>   changes ready for commit.

Why "you want to unstage them with `git reset HEAD`"?

What does `git stash` push? Does `git stash` stash working directory only , or both working directory and index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there might be some other context we don't know of here, on the point of unstaging before stashing : `git stash` *does* stash the index as well as the working tree.

From [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_description) man page :

> Use git stash when you want to record the current state of the working directory **and the index**, but want to go back to a clean working directory

(emphasis mine)

I tried it on a spare repo to confirm it and yes it does :

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 4dea0a2 Fonction ...
```

I can't (and don't want to) claim the given advice was bad because again I don't know the underlying context, but either I'm missing something or it's an overcautious and thus somewhat useless/harmless step in the process.