# Is it necessary to run `git stash push` before `git checkout`

Tags: git

`git checkout` by default leaves alone  the uncommitted changes in the working tree directory. Then is it necessary to run `git stash push`  before `git checkout` (and then run `git stash pop` at some later point after `git checkout`)? Or when is it necessary, and when is it not?

My question comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48156644/156458 and is more general.

Comment: `when is it necessary?`, don't bother, git will tell you if you need to stash. If there is a conflict, you need to stash your changes, otherwise not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If there are uncommitted changes that will be overwritten by `git checkout` the command will complain and abort. In that case `git commit` or `git stash` is necessary.

If there are uncommitted changes that will not be overwritten by `git checkout` the command succeeds and the changes spilled into the new branch. If you don't want to see these changes in the new branch use `git commit` or `git stash` before `git checkout`.

Unlike other commands (like `git pull` and `git rebase`) `git checkout` doesn't have option `--autostash` because it's meaningless: in most cases you don't want to automatically do `git stash pop` when switching to a new branch.

Comment: Thanks. Does `git checkout -m` act like a sequence of `git stash push`, `git checkout` and `git stash pop`?

Comment: `git checkout -m` does merge; it's similar to `git stash pop` but I doubt it's the same.

Comment: Why " in most cases you don't want to automatically do git stash pop when switching to a new branch"?

Comment: Because in most cases the stashed code belongs to the branched that is being put in the background, not to the branch being checked out to the work tree. In a rare case when the user wants to merge the changes into the new branch she calls `git stash apply` (or `pop`) manually.