# Does `git checkout -m` act the same as an immediate sequence of `git stash push`, `git checkout` and `git stash pop`?

Tags: git

Does `git checkout -m` act the same as an immediate sequence of `git stash push`, `git checkout` and `git stash pop`? (Yes as far as I can guess).
My question originated from [Is it necessary to run `git stash push` before `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317938/is-it-necessary-to-run-git-stash-push-before-git-checkout#comment95459886_54318188)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `git checkout -m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout--m)?

Comment: @axiac Maybe he has, but Git's official documentation is famous for being cryptic and abstract (hence SO is in business).  This is a valid question IMHO.

Comment: @Tim From what I read, yes, they are the same and your own conclusion is correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suppose the Git's documentation is famous to be cryptic and abstract for those who do not read it and prefer to "learn" from what they hear from other developers. I have always found all the answers about Git into its documentation. And this question, be it valid or not, suggests that the author didn't bother to type `git help checkout` before asking. It is sad if this is the case.